# Not getting http request response

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying get the response from a php file but not getting anything.

This is the http function which i have written to read data. The url is real and working one can test if needed.

```
exports.generate_cheksum = function () {
    console.log("generate_cheksum");

    const httpModule = require("http");
    httpModule.request({
        url: "http://tvastru.byethost7.com/paytm/generate_cheksum.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        content: JSON.stringify({
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response); //[object Object]
    }, (e) => {
        console.log("----error");
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

```
<?php

    require_once("encdec_paytm.php");

    define("merchantMid", "V********************3");
    // Key in your staging and production MID available in your dashboard
    define("merchantKey", "0***************R");

    // Key in your staging and production merchant key available in your dashboard
    define("orderId", "order1");
    define("channelId", "WEB");
    define("custId", "cust123");
    define("mobileNo", "7777777777");
    define("email", "username@emailprovider.com");
    define("txnAmount", "100.12");
    define("website", "WEBSTAGING");
    // This is the staging value. Production value is available in your dashboard
    define("industryTypeId", "Retail");
    // This is the staging value. Production value is available in your dashboard
    define("callbackUrl", "https://<Merchant_Response_URL>");
    $paytmParams = array();
    $paytmParams["MID"] = merchantMid;
    $paytmParams["ORDER_ID"] = orderId;
    $paytmParams["CUST_ID"] = custId;
    $paytmParams["MOBILE_NO"] = mobileNo;
    $paytmParams["EMAIL"] = email;
    $paytmParams["CHANNEL_ID"] = channelId;
    $paytmParams["TXN_AMOUNT"] = txnAmount;
    $paytmParams["WEBSITE"] = website;
    $paytmParams["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = industryTypeId;
    $paytmParams["CALLBACK_URL"] = callbackUrl;
    $paytmChecksum = getChecksumFromArray($paytmParams, merchantKey);
    $transactionURL = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction";
    // $transactionURL = "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction"; // for    production

    echo json_encode($paytmChecksum);
?>
```

The php file was working fine which i have tested. I just want that checksum generated as response.

Comment: I don't think the URL is still valid - http://tvastru.byethost7.com/paytm/generate_cheksum.php, it returns 404.

Comment: As @Manoj mentioned, URL is not valid

Comment: @Narendra  did you really run the URL on a browser. I'm getting an echo message of checksum on browser window.

Comment: it says `
404!
We couldn't find that page.
Please check to make sure you've typed the URL correctly.

This webserver is CaSe SenSiTiVe so ensure capital letters in the URL match the files uploaded.`

Comment: May be you have configured that domain to your localhost in your etc/host file

Comment: @Manoj ok i got it their is a spelling mistake in url

Comment: @Narendra it is checksum not cheksum in url

Comment: @Narendra you can just point http://tvastru.byethost7.com/paytm only paytm so u ll find all files i have written their. then open the file.

Comment: We copied from your question only, this one is showing string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195163/discussion-between-narendra-and-modi).

Comment: @Narendra here is the playground link you can refer

Comment: @Manoj  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=wIhBby

Comment: You might have to check with your hosting service, it redirects the requests and uses JavaScript to inject a hash code on cookie, this wouldn't allow non browser applications to access your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that Byet Host implement a simple security antibots module >named testcookie-nginx-module https://kyprizel.github.io/testcookie-nginx-module/

That's most likely a bot protection plugin on your server. If you have control over your server plugins, you should disable / remove it. If it's also just a free hoster you probably can't disable it. In that case this hoster is useless for you and you should search for a new hoster.

I tested your code on my server with my paytm details. it's working fine

Comment: I think free hosting service is what causing this problem. I'll buy one soon.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thing you need to do

1. Point to correct URL. (http://tvastru.byethost7.com/paytm/generate_checksum.php)
2. You must explicitly set cleartextTrafficPermitted  (android:usesCleartextTraffic="true") in your Android.manifest file.
3. // Content property of the response is HttpContent
   // The toString method allows you to get the response body as string.
   `.then((response) => {console.log(response); //[object Object]}`
4. When your php code is getting called from App, it is returning `This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support` That probably has nothing to do with your code, check your hosting service.